# Should I use Flask or Django?

Tags: web-apps, python

I'm going to create a simple web page - couple of presentation pages mostly plus `form` for orders (there should be a small db to store orders). It should have `admin` interface for price changing and orders viewing.

I can't figure out which would be better - `Django` or `Flask`

Normaly, I would go with `Django` but I've read a lot of opinions that `Django` is overkill for such pages etc.

I like `Django` admin and ORM and I can work with `Django`.

What would you recommend and why? What disadvantages would be to go with `Django`?

Comment: Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So what specific features do you need that we can give recommendations for – which then might be something else than Flask or Django, but might well include those? Must the software be free, or would you accept payed solutions (up to which price)?